# Looking for source of Navaids and fixes for an application I am writing

Tags: faa, navaids

I was able to get a list of airports and runways from the FAA site but cannot seem to find a list of these items.  https://www.openaip.net/navaids?field_openaip_navaid_type_value_many_to_one=2&title=&field_openaip_navaid_id_value=&field_openaip_navaid_country_value_many_to_one=237 has a list but no way to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [28-Day NASR Subscription site](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription/) you can reach [the current NASR Subscription page](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription_2022-03-24/) which includes the following downloads:

https://nfdc.faa.gov/webContent/28DaySub/2022-03-24/FIX.zip
https://nfdc.faa.gov/webContent/28DaySub/2022-03-24/NAV.zip

which contain plaintext information about all waypoints and navigational aids in the NAS.

The page also includes [a download](https://nfdc.faa.gov/webContent/28DaySub/2022-03-24/aixm5.1.zip) of the above information in AIXM 5.1 format.

There are also fix/waypoint search functions available on the [AIS](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Loc_ID_Search/Fixes_Waypoints/) and [NFDC](https://nfdc.faa.gov/nfdcApps/services/ajv5/fixes.jsp) sites. These are not "downloads" per se but you could use GUI scripting to scrape the fix names from the AIS site, for example.

The [FAA Data Portal](https://www.faa.gov/data) may be helpful, although for aeronautical data it seems to link back to the AIS site listed above.

Comment: Does the FAA publish the sectors *within* each Center?  I've seen plenty of maps that show the borders of the various ARTCC's, but something that describes the sectors within each Center seems harder to find.  Do you happen to know if that's available nationally, or is it a matter of seeing what each individual center happens to make available?  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure you intended this comment to go here? But I know that ZBW publishes a [Letter to Airmen (or would that be a Letter to Air Missions?)](https://notams.aim.faa.gov/lta/main/viewlta?lookupid=2719897123687503303) depicting the internal sectors. I'm not sure if any centers do that, but you can try a [NOTAM search](https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/nsapp.html#/) and see what you come up with.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  thanks!